# Why udev is preferring label over ID_SERIAL

Tags: linux, udev

Lets say i have a disk **/dev/sdc**,Assume ID_SERIAL for that disk is **36000c292879f425e5d10aa537f7b57e5**

And i wrote below rule file **70-persistentdisk.rules**

```
KERNEL=="sdc", OWNER:="grid", GROUP:="asmadmin"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="36000c292879f425e5d10aa537f7b57e5" , OWNER:="root" , GROUP:="disk" , MODE:="0660"
```

I have triggered the udev rules by below command

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

When I get disk permission on /dev/sdc

```
input: ls -ld /dev/sdc
output:brw-rw----. 1 grid asmadmin 8, 32 Jul  8 02:09 /dev/sdc
```

But I expect it SDC to be set to root and disk instead of the grid,asmadmin

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: No-one around to help out or no information allover?